# how to get union of pojos in this case

Tags: java

i have below POJOS:

```
public class ApplicationVersionsData{
      private List<MajorVersion> majorVersions;
}
public class MajorVersion{
     private  List<Revision> revisions;
}
public class Revision{
      private List<Role> roles;
}
public class Role{
     private String roleName;
     private List<String> scopes;
}
```

```
one application may has many major versions.  (v1,v2,v3)
one major version has many revisions.  (v1 may have 1.0.0,1.1.0,1.1.1)
one revision has many Roles.(role1,role2,role3)
```

if i want to get All role names except for a particular revision ,
what is the best way to get ??

please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
majorVersions
    .stream()
    .flatMap(mv -> mv.revisions())
    .filter(this::isNotParticularRevision)
    .flatMap(revision -> revision.roles())
    .map(role -> role.roleName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`isNotParticularRevision(Revision revision)` returns `boolean` true/false based on whether the revision passed to it is the one you want to exclude. You need to write an `.equals()` method for the class `Revision`.

Edit: As mentioned in one of the comments below, it should be `mv.revisions().stream()` and `revision.roles().stream()`.

Comment: @sleepToken try it, there's no coming back. And then, reactive streams.

Comment: I guess it should be `.flatMap(mv -> mv.revisions().stream())`

Comment: @RAMLNP did this solve your problem? If yes, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within each class that contains a list, I would write a getter method `getAllItems()` where [Item] is replaces by majorVersions, revisions, roles...

```
private List<Item> getAllItems() {
  // return the list
}
```

Then, from the parent:

```
// I haven't tested this you may need to tweak syntax
for (MajorVersion version : majorVersions) {
  for (Revision revision : version.getAllRevisions()) {
    // print/pass the revision we are currently in

    for (Role role : revision.getAllRoles() {
      // print or return role
    }
  }
}
```